# FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly. Access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7

**Пациент:**
Windws Server 2008 R2 x64
IIS 7.5.7600.16385
.NET Fraemwork v2.0

**Проблема:**

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.1.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=edbe51ad942a3f5c' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

**Попытки решить проблему:**
- На папку и на dll предоставил права для `Everyone` и `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` **Full Control**  *не помогло*
- Включение `Load User Profile` *не помогло*
- Включение `32 битного режима` *не помогло*
- Запуск пула под `NetworkService` конечно решает проблему, но желание разобраться с `ApplicationPoolIdentity`